# Preencher tabela com dados digitado no JTextField, separados por virgula

Tags: java, swing

Tenho o código abaixo de um `JTextField`, onde queria digitar números separados por virgula, e que ao clicar no `JButton`, os dados fossem adicionados numa coluna da tabela.

```
public class Dados extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public Dados() {
        initComponents();
    }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        vNomes = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        jLabel1.setText("Digite os valores separados por virgula");

        jButton1.setText("Formar tabela");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "classes", "Xi", "Fi", "Fac"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(vNomes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 343, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(88, 88, 88)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(214, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(vNomes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(412, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField vNomes;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Apresente um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o codigo e simular o problema.

Comment: Não tem nada implementado ai sobre a duvida, o que voce ja tentou fazer?

Comment: nao sei fazer nada, somente sei a logica que seria digitar numeros para preencher as colunas da tabela , por exemplo a coluna Xi, fazendo a primeira depois farei as proximas.

Comment: Sua duvida dessa forma é muito ampla. Sugiro da uma lida sobre JTable, aprender um pouco a manusear e tentar algo, e quando pintar uma duvida especifica, perguntar novamente.

Comment: A nao ser que o quer voce queira, na verdade, é fazer um texto digitado num textfield ser inserido numa coluna, mas sua pergunta nao especifica qual coluna e se será fixa a adicao nessa coluna.

Comment: isso mesmo,  texto digitado, apos clicar no button, preencha a coluna, pode ser qq uma, e pode ser fixa

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor como essa adição deve ser feita, senao fica dificil elaborar algo.

Comment: ok,vamos la, preciso preencher uma tabela com alguns numeros que serao digitados, esses numeros devem preencher uma coluna na tabela, exemplo a coluna Xi, quando o usuario digita, 1,2,3,4,5... clica no botao adiconar, cada valor preenche uma linha da coluna, entendeu?

Comment: Cada valor de coluna é separado por virgula? E se tiver mais valores com virgula do que colunas?

Comment: nao, cada valor  sera para uma linha.. da mesma coluna ficaria:

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode pegar o texto do `JTextField` e usar o método [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) para separar os valores separados por virgula para, em seguida, adicionar na tabela. Como está usando `DefaultTableMoldel`, você pode utilizar o método [`addRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow-java.lang.Object:A-) para adicionar as linhas.

Pra evitar adições quando o campo não possuir nada, utilizei o método [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) para remover espaços vazios na `String` capturada do campo, e a condicional para verificar se essa *string* não está vazia.

Não consegui reproduzir seu código, parece que foi gerado pelo *netbeans*, mas veja funcionando no exemplo que elaborei abaixo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Dados2 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Dados2().setVisible(true));
    }

    public Dados2() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 300));
        contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panelField = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panelField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        textField = new JTextField();
        panelField.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(20);

        String[] columnNames = new String[] { "classes", "Xi", "Fi", "Fac" };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

        contentPane.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panelBtn = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panelBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton jbutton = new JButton("Adicionar");
        panelBtn.add(jbutton);

        jbutton.addActionListener(e -> {

            String text = textField.getText();

            if (text.length() > 0 && text.contains(",")) {

                String[] values = text.split(",");

                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    model.addRow(new Object[] { null, values[i], null, null });
                }
            }
        });
        pack();
    }
}
```

Funcionando:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Vale ressaltar que, além da string vazia, a condicional também checa se há virgulas na string, o que faz com que texto simples não seja adicionado a uma unica linha. Se quiser alterar este comportamento, basta remover a condicional `text.contains(",")`.

Comment: Nossa ficou top vou testar e tentar implementar as outras colunas, muito obrigado

Comment: @Claudio voce pode marcar a resposta como aceita, se ela lhe ajudou ;)

Comment: Só uma perguntinha: se eu quiser pegar esse dados digitados e armazenar cada um numa variável para fazer cálculos com os números digitados antes de mostrar na tabela, daria pra aproveitar esse método?

Comment: @Claudio se voce reparar no listener, logo após capturar o texto do campo, eu criei um array de string contendo os valores separados por virgula em cada um de seus indices, basta usar esse array. Provavelmente voce precisará fazer cast para inteiro, pois mesmo que sejam números, eles são strings.